# Regular expressions matching

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I have one function for checking, whether entered line is "OK".

```
#include <tr1/regex>

bool lineIsValid(string line) {
    const tr1::regex pattern("[^-]{1,30} - [^-]{1,30}");
    return tr1::regex_match(line, pattern);
}

lineIsValid("test - test");
```

the function returns false. Why?

Comment: This matches fine for me.  Are you sure your input is identical to what you posted here?

Comment: Ya I just copied and pasted your code and I get true, double check that your input is correct.

Comment: Given Aito's post, you should consider using `boost::regex` instead if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the syntax is ok, but depends on the implementation.
Check this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/d3d5ead8-f5a3-4b59-9d7b-5ba8c4f0ef01/).

Or [this](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/language-c-moderated/593327-help-tr1-regex_match.html):

> After further investigation, I (we) have determined that the TR1
>    framework supplied by Microsoft with Visual Studio 2008 [and
>   some very early versions of Visual Studio 2010] is buggy, which makes
>   me wonder why the other regex's supplied by Dinkumware are not buggy.
>   Or are they?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that should match.

Is there potentially a bug in the implementation of the tr1 library?  Maybe it is getting confused with the "-" that is used as the range specifier.